# using one ajax call with json, or two ajax calls with html?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, performance

I have an element that contain many messages.
each message is an HTML element

```
<div class="items">
    <other-non-related-elements ...>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>title</h4>
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" ...
</div>
```

This content is being updated constantly with ajax calls.
They way it's done: the php code is producing a ready-to-print html. and the JQuery code is removing the elements and appending the new ones.

```
$.get('url',null,
function(data){
  $(".items .item").remove();
  $(".items").append(data);
}
```

Now i need to add an single (not `item`) element to the `<items>` element.
it should be like this

```
<div class="items">
    <new element>content</new element>
    <other-non-related-elements ...>
    <div class="item">
      <h4>title</h4>
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item" ...
</div>
```

In order to keep it as a single ajax call, the php will have to produce a json code, that the jquery will manipulate into html elements. since the page is already very busy with other js code, i'm not sure that it's a better solution.

the other solution is to make two ajax calls. one for the `new-element` and one fot the items.

Any advice? ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother about client performance if not necessary.
Make one AJAX call and sort things out with client-side JS.
Remember that your server has to process lots of requests but the web browser has to deal with only a couple of requests.
So if you can always put the job on the client-side - he/she won't notice but they'll definitely notice if your server is constantly bombarded with lots of incoming requests.
Grab JSON and let JS do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I'd keep it one Ajax call. Json is probably the best for that, as you mentioned. Alternatively and depending on your structure, PHP can return pure HTML, and JavaScript/jQuery can then put it in place using the innerHTML method.