# CakePHP 1.2.x - Ajax Pagination 'Next Page' Does Not Update, Stays on 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

Good day all,

I am extremely comfortable in using CakePHP 2.x but am having to work on a much older CakePHP 1.2.x app at the moment.

I have implemented an Ajax pagination, which works perfectly fine for the first page, however the 'Next Page' link never does go past page 2. So even once page 2 is loaded, my paginator's next link still remains 'page:2'.

The difference is that my paginator links are GLOBAL. I do not load the pagination links as part of the new DOM injected HTML. The paginator links sit outside of my ajax container, and the content is loaded into the container on click. The paginator links are NOT loaded into that container.

I am well aware that CakePHP 2.x employs the `$this->Js->WriteBuffer();` method to print out core JS, which as far as I know is used (amongst other things) to update the pagination links.

CakePHP 1.2.x to my knowledge does not have such a method.

Can anyone shed some light or offer some opinions on this?

My included components & helpers:

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');
var $helpers = array('Javascript', 'Html', 'Form', 'Paginator');
```

My pagination:

```
$paginator->next('<h3>Next Page </h3>',array('escape'=>false));
```

I have an Ajax view and an Ajax layout for these ajax loads. The Ajax view just contains the content I want to load, literally just the loop. The ajax layout is ONLY a single line of `<?php echo $content_for_layout ?>`

I have placed this at the end of my ajax layout, but to no avail:

```
<?php echo $javascript->writeEvents(); ?>
```

Any help will be mega appreciated.

Simon

---

UPDATE: Adding JS code in head, and Ajax view code

**Head loaded JS:**

```
$javascript->link('jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js', false);
$javascript->link('scrollads.js', false);
$javascript->link('jquery.form.js', false);
$javascript->link('jquery.form-defaults.js', false);
$javascript->link('jquery.jplayer.min.js', false);
$javascript->link('jquery.sparkline.min.js', false);
```

$javascript->link('jquery.cookie.js', false);
$javascript->link('jquery.tweet.js', false);
    $javascript->link('flowplayer.min.js', false);
    $javascript->link('jquery.validate.min.js', false);
    $javascript->link('coin-slider.min.js', false);
    $javascript->link('jquery.thslide.min.js', false);
    $javascript->link('jquery.barousel.min.js', false);
    $javascript->link('behaviour.js', false);
    echo "";
    echo "";
    echo "jQuery.noConflict();";

```
echo $asset->scripts_for_layout();
```

**Ajax View File:**

```
<?php foreach ($galleries as $gallery): ?>
                <div class="albumcontainer-wrapper">
                    <div class="albumcontainer-top"></div>
                        <div class="albumcontainer">
                            <a href="<?php echo Router::url('/gallery_images/index/'.$gallery['Gallery']['id']); ?>">
                                <?php echo $html->image($gallery['GalleryImage'][0]['Image']['default']['path_adjusted']); ?>
                            </a>
                            <h3><?php echo $gallery['Gallery']['title']; ?></h3>
                        </div>
                    <div class="albumcontainer-bottom"></div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php echo $javascript->WriteEvents(true); ?>
```

**This is how I append the ajax loaded view to the existing content rather than replace it:**

```
$paginator->options(
                    array(
                        'update' => 'ajaxAppendGalleries', 
                        'indicator' => false,
                        'evalScripts' => true,
                        'complete' => 'var tmp = jQuery("#ajaxAppendGalleries").html(); jQuery("#galleryContainer").append(tmp); tmp = null; jQuery("#ajaxAppendGalleries").empty();',
                        )
                    );
```

Comment: Can you add the html/js structure?

Comment: Sure, are you referring to the HTML structure of the Ajax loaded view, and the JS structure in the head of the main layout?

Comment: yes. is it possible that the js-events are becoming irrelevant after the first load?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine so no, because the instruction is constant: when clicking on the next link, ajax load the paged result into X container. Updating my question now. Thanks for your input so far, really appreciate you jumping on board man.

Comment: My load more ajax button is simply the next paginator option: `echo $paginator->next('<h3>Load More</h3>',array('escape'=>false));`

Comment: What i miss (maybe my english) is: the problem is with the client or with the server? i mean: does the link send a request? does the server reply?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, there is nothing wrong with the ajax load at all, it will load content every time I click, but it never loads past page 2. Example: I load page, I click 'See More Videos' and it loads page 2 into ajax container. But, if I click again, ajax works but instead of page 3, pge 2 is loaded again. So the ajax pagination is not being updated at all.

Comment: And, this part `$paginator->next('<h3>Next Page </h3>',array('escape'=>false));` is also updated after the ajax load?

Comment: No, it's not. None of them are. But if I remove ajax and have normal pagination it works. But I cannot do that, the client wants ajax pagination, appending results to the page.

Comment: So, my advice is: try using json. send the pagination code also back. let the helper create it based on the current page..

Comment: Can you perhaps give a small example? So basically I would use the Ajax helper and not the paginator helper??

Comment: I'll try to pseudo it.

And no, use the paginator-helper, just keep in mind that when cake is creating the records based on the page, it also create some information that will be used by the paginator later.

Comment: also, check this link. it might be more clear (the same technique, very similar use) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687986/using-one-ajax-call-with-json-or-two-ajax-calls-with-html

Answer (score 0):

This will be pseudo since i am not familiar with cake 1.2
and although i assume that some of it is trivial, these are points that should be 'check listed'

In the controller's function:
Make sure that you are sending json content with empty layout and with no debugging info.

In the view, create a json structure similar to this:

```
data{
  paginationHtml: {htmlContent: /* here comes the output of the navigation-creation-function of the  paginator-helper*/, 
  anyOtherContent: ""},
  pageContentHtml: /* the iteration that print out the paged content itself */
}
```

In the original page use jquery to load the content and replace the `innerHTML` of the paged data, as well as the content of the pagination navigation links.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying, but if I use your method then I might as well not use the pagination helper at all, and I might as well only  make use of the Ajax helper, and write my own pagination into the page?

Comment: Not at all. the opposite. you willl use the paginator, just in the right context - meaning: in the context of the current page call\load

Comment: I honestly am not understanding at all how this would be implemented? I cannot implement the pagination on the ajax loaded page, because that would remove my requirement for a global pagination. I don't think we are on the same level of understanding.

Comment: Please check this: http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Pagination.html.
 AND NOTE: there is an ajax-pagination sub-section. it will explain it much better :)

Comment: Hi Yossi, I have checked the cake book extensively before posting on stackoverflow ;) I do not think that you understand my problem? The ajax loading DOES work, and my content DOES load correctly, the only problem I have is that the pagination does not update, even when I add the $javascript->WriteEvents(true); code to my ajax layout and my ajax view... I am starting to think that maybe with all the jQuery plugins being used in the app, there is a possible conflict that is denying prototype the ability to update the pagination number to include the correct 'next page' link.

Comment: @SimonDowdles 
lets try something else. would you like to share some files? :)
As to your assumptions, maybe i do get it wrong. what do you mean by "pagination"? as i understand it - your problem is that the "next" button is always pointing at the secong page...

Comment: You are 100% correct yes, my next button is always pointing to the second page. i.e the ajax loaded page is missing, or not containing the necessary js to update the pagination number.

Comment: Even if I remove ALL jQuery scripts and plugins and ONLY load prototype and scriptaculous, it still does not update the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Simon, suspect whats happening is that your click events are being bound to the original DOM object when document.ready(), so when your Ajax call occurs and the paginated content is replaced, the events aren't attached to the replacement DOM object.

I know in jQuery you can use the

```
$(document).on('event','#target',function(){})
```

[syntax](https://api.jquery.com/on/)  to ensure that the event is permanently bound to all objects on the page, regardless of when/how they load and I did see an example in the [Cake Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#other-methods) (scroll down to Js::event) today that suggested you could use it ... although note the .bind() method is deprecated in current version of jQuery, use .on() instead. I'm afraid I don't know if that's possible in 1.2, but you could augment your use of this JS helper with some manual jQuery if you had to.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Since 1.2.x uses prototype as it's JS framework, I don't see it as being possible, but yes one sure could augment the existing JS helper or paginator, but I was really hoping to implement a simple fix for the default pagination. As it stands now, I think it's going to be a LOT easier for me to implement my own Ajax load using jQueries $.ajax methods, and only use the cake paginator to keep track of the current page, total pages etc, using those values to control my custom pagination. Sigh... How I wish this was a Cake 2.x project instead

Comment: ok yes, you're right, I forgot about prototype. If it helps, I had done this before. I have a snippet of code I could post if SE would let me ... it's a few characters too long.

Comment: `$('#tableContainer').find('th > a, ul.pagination a').click(function(e){ //ajax call })` this takes care of the th col headings as well as the pagination (assuming you set your selectors). Mine involved an ajax post of a search for at the top of the table to set conditions on the pagination.

Comment: Hi again. I hear you on the custom ajax call yes, and that is what I started implementing yesterday. I honestly think that somewhere there is a jQuery conflict preventing prototype from updating the ajax pagination link... That's the most viable reason I think. I think I am going to attempt to do the following: Bind a click event to my pagination, make an ajax request to page 2, capture the loaded HTML and append it to my desired div, and then use some javascript to increment a page number variable. I can then use the pagination helper on my initial load to determine the total pages to page...

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I haven't worked with Prototype (ever) but I think it also uses $. In which case you'd need to either specific jQuery.noConflict() and modify your API calls appropriately.

Comment: Simon, I learned something else today when working with 2.4 ajax pagination. For some reason - not clear why - this issue of ajax working on one paginate click but not the next raised its ugly head with me. The answer - copy the buffer flush into yoru VIEW AS WeLL AS YOUR TEMPLATE - when using RequestComponent, the layout - where cake cookbook tells you to put the flush buffer - of course isnt' used. it uses ajax layout, which doesn't have a flush buffer call. Try that, let me know if it works. It did for me :)